# check for touched ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, ontouchlistener

I am creating an interface where you can turn dots on/off by touching them, but if i try to detect if the imageview is touched, it only detects taps, and not when i touch multiple dots at once.

Example:
when i click on a dot, it lights up. But when i swipe over multiple dots, only the first dot i touched will light up, and not all dots i touched.

I currently have an onTouchlistener set up like this:

```
v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
        if(toState == 1){
            view.setImageResource(R.mipmap.dot_on);
        }else if(toState == 0){
            view.setImageResource(R.mipmap.dot_off);
        }

        return false;
    }
v});
```

'toState' is changed by a button so you can toggle between turning the dots on or turning them off.

Can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

EDIT

the activity:

```
public class new_frame extends AppCompatActivity {
        public int toState = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_frame);
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        final ToggleButton toStateBTN = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        toStateBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(toState == 1){
                toState = 0;
            }else if(toState == 0){
                toState = 1;
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int Dim = width / 24;
    RelativeLayout View = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Layout);
    for (int i = 0;i<View.getChildCount();i++) {
        View v = View.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof ImageView) {
            //((ImageView) v).setMaxHeight(ledDim);
            //((ImageView) v).setMaxWidth(ledDim);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();
            Log.d("NewFrame", "child found: " + v.getId() + ". Set dimensions from " + params.height + "," + params.width + " to " + Dim + "," + Dim);
            params.width = Dim;
            params.height = Dim;
            v.setLayoutParams(params);
            v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
                    if(toState == 1){
                        view.setImageResource(R.mipmap.dot_on);
                    }else if(toState == 0){
                        view.setImageResource(R.mipmap.dot_off);
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
  }
}
```

the xml is just 200 dots, with a button next to it. The button and the dots work, i can tap dots on/off, i just can't get the swipe on/off functionality to work.

Comment: use combination of gesture lister with touch listener

Answer (score 0):

You can do as following. Set same code for every kind of Motion Event. And also return **TRUE**:

```
v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) {
        final ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
        switch (arg1.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

            if(toState == 1){
               view.setImageResource(R.mipmap.dot_on);
            }else if(toState == 0){
               view.setImageResource(R.mipmap.dot_off);
            }
            break;
          }

          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:{

           if(toState == 1){
               view.setImageResource(R.mipmap.dot_on);
           }else if(toState == 0){
               view.setImageResource(R.mipmap.dot_off);
          }
            break;        
          }

          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

             if(toState == 1){
                view.setImageResource(R.mipmap.dot_on);
             }else if(toState == 0){
                view.setImageResource(R.mipmap.dot_off);
             }
           break;
          }
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: What problems are you facing? Can you add full activity and layout to your queation please?

Comment: There is a slight update in v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() line. You may try out.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reaction, i have been very busy.   It still doesn't work, i still have the same problem as before.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself, since none of your suggestions worked.

I made it work using a lot of Rects with an onTouchListener on the main view (parent of the dots' view).

In the onCreate() method I initiated a Rect[] with a Rect for every dot i have.

```
for (int i=0;i<v.getChildCount;i++) {
    Rects[i] = new Rect(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom());
}
```

Then in the onTouchListener of the main view I check if one of the Rects contains the location marked in the OnTouchListener. If one of them does, i turn them on/off.

```
mainView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {         
        for (int i=0;i<v.getChildCount;i++) {
            if (Rects[i].contains((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY())) {
                 //turn dot on/off
            }
        }
    }
}
```